# How to check app response from localhost with only 1 terminal

Tags: python, bash, flask, makefile, localhost

- I normally test my app by opening *another* terminal (client), and send post requests *from there*.
- In that window, I compare the results I *received* to the results I had expected.
- How can I automate this process? (for example as a `Makefile` target `check_app`).

Here is a minimal example (*server*):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Final

RAISE: Final[int] = 33

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/analyze", methods=["POST"])
def update_salary() -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    return jsonify([
        {
            "name": entry["name"],
            "salary": entry["salary"]+RAISE
        }
        for entry in request.get_json()
        if request.is_json
    ])
```

and here is the *client*

```
import json
import requests
from typing import Final

URL: Final[str] = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/analyze"

with open("input.json") as fl:
    data = json.load(fl)

response = requests.post(URL, json=data)

for entry in response.json():
    name = entry["name"]
    new_salary = entry["salary"]
    print(f"Hey {name} your new salary is {new_salary}")
```

The steps I do are:

```
$ flask run # automagically runs wsgi.py in terminal 1
$ python main.py    # sends post request in terminal 2
```

**EDIT**
Here is my *unsuccessful* attempt based on the comments:

```
.ONESHELL:
test:
    @kill -9 $$(lsof -t -i tcp:5000)
    @flask run &
    @cd ../sender
    @python main.py > received.txt
    @diff received.txt expected.txt
    @cd -
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oren/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/oren/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/oren/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Could [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) be a solution for your problem. E.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156308/automatically-create-screen-sessions-to-run-tasks-in-parallel

Comment: The actual screens don't have to exist, but the `Makefile` should somehow be able to set up the communication, then do a `diff` on the received json file

Comment: How does your Makefile look at the moment? Have you tried it already?

Comment: I don't know how to "transfer" control between the terminals. I do the `flask run`, then I have no clue how to continue

Comment: You could send the first script in the background and then move further with the second script. I never tried it with a Makefile, so you have to test it. [shell in background example](https://www.linuxtechi.com/run-linux-shell-command-in-background/)

Comment: As @jerik says, if you do `flask run &`, you'll get your prompt back and be able to run your Python main code. If you want to avoid seeing any terminal output from `flask`, use `flask run > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I made an unsuccessful attempt at this and pasted it in the question as an EDIT section.

Comment: You might `sleep` for 2 seconds before starting your Python to let flask get started... just guessing.

Comment: @Philippe note the `.ONESHELL:` before ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete makefile based on the comments from @Mark Setchell:

```
.ONESHELL:
test:
    @echo "[ - ] testing app"
    @kill -9 $$(lsof -t -i tcp:5000)
    @flask run 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
    @sleep 2
    @cd ../sender
    @python main.py > received.txt
    @if cmp -s -- received.txt expected.txt; \
    then echo "[ > ] PASS  "; else echo "[ - ] ERROR "; fi
    @cd - 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Is this the correct and working answer? If so, please accept it so other folks know. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, but I can accept my own answer only tomorrow (there is a minimum time gap to accept your own answers)